# How to get metadata from MongoDB with Breeze

Tags: node.js, mongodb, breeze

Currently I have a project using WebAPI and EF with Breeze, it works fine with Metadata stuffs for validation on server but when migrating to NodeJS and MongoDB, I get stuck for trying get Metadata from MongoDB. I checked out zza BMEAN app but I just saw on this project:

```
        app.get('/breeze/Breeze/Metadata', getMetadata);

 function getMetadata(req, res, next) {
    next({
        statusCode: 404,
        message: "No metadata from the server; metadata is defined on the client"
    });
}
```

I also read all document about Breeze/MongoDB but still doesn't help me to get Metadata for this.
The main point is I just want to change backend with BMEAN instead of WebAPI+EF+Breeze, don't need to change code on client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The metadata is provided by EF, not by MongoDB.  If you are using a CodeFirst approach with EF then you should already have a DBContext.

This talks about how to use the DBContext -

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entity-framework-dbcontext

This talks about how to use EF as a design tool to build your meta data from classes -

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/ef-design-tool

Odds are you already have what you need to generate the metadata it is just extending that and exposing a service to provide it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

PW Kad's answer is correct, but to clarify, there is no way to get metadata from a MongoDB database because the database itself has an indeterminate structure. So you have to tell your client what the structure is.  If you want to use the same client code for EF and Mongo then saving the metadata provided by the EFContext in your Mongo project makes a lot of sense.  In other cases simply define the metadata directly on the client via Breeze's metadata api calls.

Comment: And there are examples of writing client-side metadata in JS both in the documentation and in the "Zza" sample.